# Embed a localhost URL in QR Code

Tags: url, localhost

I'm just wondering is it possible to embed a localhost URL e.g.
    `http://localhost/sampleproj/addsection.php?seatID=2` 
in a qr code, so when the code is scanned this will render on an Android/IPhone devide?

I'm only wondering if its possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean if scanned on a phone on the same network? You would need to reference by IP address not `localhost`, but yes, if you're on the same network as the computer hosting the website this would work.

Answer (score 3):

Sure!   Go to  http://invx.com/  and type the URL you want to encode.   There's nothing particular about a QR Code that makes it work as a link, it's just that the reader app will recognise that the code you scanned is a URL and assume you intended to visit the address.

(But if it's `localhost` then it will only work on the computer that's running the website)